# algorithm to find the relatively most cost effective combination

Tags: algorithm

In the game i played it has a crafting system which has many kinds of materials (A, B, C, D, E ... ect) and many kinds of item recipes.

All the materials are untradable and can't be sold directly so the mat on its own has 0 value.

The crafted item can be sold directly to NPC and has a fixed value.

Each item has only one recipe associated with it.

Each recipe costs 1 to 5 types of materials to craft

For example `item1` requires `30 mat A + 40 mat B` and can be sold for `10` gold.

So the question is: Given all the recipes and their crafted item's value, how can i create an ordered list based on their cost effectiveness.

For example if `item1` takes `1 mat A` to craft and can be sold for `10` gold, `item2` takes `2 mat A` to craft and can be sold for `15` gold. Then `item1` is more cost effective than `item2` since `10 > (15 / 2)`

Another example: item1 takes 1 matA and sells for 10 gold, item2 takes 10 matB and sells for 1 gold. item3 takes 1 matA, 5 matB and sells for 15 gold. Then item3 would be the most cost efficient recipe to craft

I thought of doing something similar to knapsack problem but i fail to come up with a DP table since the cost of mat is 100% relative to other recipes.

Comment: Do you know the drop ratio of different mats? You can use that to assess their “cost” in farming time.

Comment: This problem sounds good :)

Comment: @RoyShahaf mats only drop in daily dungeon and can't be farmed. So i am trying to get the most out of them.

Comment: Judging from your formula you don't care which materials are used, only the amount is important. So this becomes very simple: order by selling price divided by the sum of material amounts (descending).

Comment: @maraca some materials are more valuable than the other. for example item1 costs mat1 x1 and sells for 10 gold, item2 costs mat2 x 10 and sells for 1 gold. item3 costs mat1 x1 and mat2 x5 and sells for 15 gold. item1 has the lowest price/amount while item3 has the highest cost efficiency

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming

Comment: @n.m. thanks for the link! it surely looks like the same problem. The algorithm seems complicated though :(

Comment: Did somebody promise you this job would be easy? :) The articles do list existing open source solvers you could probably use though, so not all is lost.